# How to get list of all bookmarks in Zathura

Tags: pdf-reader

How in [*Zathura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(document_viewer)) get a list of all bookmarks? I take the `blist` command from [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zathura.1.html), write it, and *the wrong number of arguments* is returned to me. Which argument to insert for get a list ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write `blist` command + <kbd>Tab</kbd> , and you'll see all your bookmarks.

Comment: Or if you're short on time just `bl` and Tab.

Answer (score 4):

zathura now lists all bookmarks with `:blist` command without any additional argument (tested on v0.4.7).

However, to *jump* to a bookmark, the command is `:blist <bookmark>`, for this tab completion helps.